# Dispatch multiply actions in order in effect - ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm wondering how I dispatch multiply actions in order in my effect.

```
  @Effect()
  getClients$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(ClientActions.GET_CLIENTS)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store.select(fromRoot.getClients))
    .filter(([action, clients]) => clients.length === 0)
    .map(action => new LayoutActions.IsLoading(true))
    .switchMap(() => this.clientService.getClients())
    .map(clients => new ClientActions.GetClientsReceived(clients));
```

In the above example the first action is not dispatched. The getClients() method and last action are working correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every action emitted by your observable will be dispatched so what you need is map an action to multiple actions. You can do that by adding the loading action with `startWith()` on your `switchMap()` :

```
.switchMap(action => {
  this.clientService.getClients()
    .map(clients => new ClientActions.GetClientsReceived(clients) as Action)
    .startWith(new LayoutActions.IsLoading(true))
);
```

Sometimes typings can be wrong, typescript will use the specific type of your action instead of `Action`. In this case after the map, the Observable is typed as `Observable<ClientActionReceived>` so returning a `LayoutActionLoading` inside startWith seems wrong for typescript.
To avoid that you need to cast one of the two as `Action` so it'll know it's an `Observable<Action>`.

Comment: To prevent typescript error I needed to modify the last line to .startWith(<any> new LayoutActions.IsLoading(true)) . Would be great if you can add that in your answer.

Comment: I've add some explanation about that typing issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use the do operator.

Example:
`.do(dispatchAction(...))`

Answer (score 0):

i am doing it like that:

```
userRoleChange$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
 .ofType(userActions.USER_SWITCH_ROLE)
 .switchMap(() => Observable.of(
   {type: preFlightActions.PRE_FLIGHT_CLEAR, payload: {}},
   {type: detailPlanningActions.DETAIL_PLANNING_CLEAR, payload: {}},
   {type: uploadsActions.UPLOAD_FILTER_SET, payload: {}}
 ));
```